# How to export an Imagine Collection to Cloud Storage in the Google Earth Engine code editor?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

fitoprincipe has a great tool that is documented here https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch.

However this tool only supports batch exports to drive and assets. I can't find any other way other than to switch to the python API. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own custom function for use with any of the Export.Image.to functions. Here's an example for `toCloudStorage`, with a demonstration of how to use it in the link below.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8ea9c972310dba8a37e153cdf54f35b

```js
function exportImageCollectionToCloudStorage(imgColl,args){
  /* args: a dictionary of arguments for Export.image.toCloudStorage
    excluding fileNamePrefix, description, and image
  */
var n = imgColl.size()
var imgList = imageCollection.toList(n)
var nList = ee.List.sequence(0,n.subtract(1))
var names = imageCollection.aggregate_array("system:index")
var info = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(names,nList).getInfo()
Object.keys(info).forEach(function(name,n){
  var fileNamePrefix = name;  // Optionally format this some other way
  var description = "EXPORT_" + name;  // Optionally format this some other way
  var image = ee.Image(imgList.get(n))
  var exportOptions = {
    fileNamePrefix: fileNamePrefix,
    description: description,
    image:image,
  }
  for (var x in args) exportOptions[x] = args[x];
  Export.image.toCloudStorage(exportOptions)
})
return;
}
```

In python, you could use [geemap.ee_export_image_collection_to_cloud_storage](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/blob/master/geemap/common.py#L581)

Comment: This seems to work too: https://medium.com/@zrowland/exporting-images-and-imagecollections-from-google-earth-engine-to-your-local-machine-412a51d05283